# Access Static Members of a Class from Another Class in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, class, oop, static

I have 2 classes, Class A

```dart
class A {
  static void one() {
    print('One');
  }
}
```

and Class B

```dart
class B {
  static void two() {
    print('Two');
  }
}
```

I want to access the static members of these classes from a third Class C

```dart
class C {
  // Todo
}
```

What operations can I do to achieve this?

```dart
void main() {
  C.one(); // 'One'
  C.two(); // 'Two'
}
```

I want to access the static members of classes A and B from class C without creating the object of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating static methods to access the static members of class A and B

```dart
class C {
  static void one() {
    A.one();
  }

  static void two() {
    B.two();
  }
}
```